# "Sometimes astronomers find thing they ..." or "Sometimes astronomers find things they ..."

Tags: plural-forms, singular

I read the following in science magazine:

> Sometimes astronomers find **thing** they weren't even looking for. Here's eight of the best ...

Why didn't they use "things"?

> Sometimes astronomers find **things** they weren't even looking for. Here's eight of the best ...

Comment: a typo, probably

Comment: @CowperKettle is correct; the example you provided should use "find things" or possibly "find something" rather than "find thing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is probably a typo in the magazine.

The word "thing" is usually a countable noun, and so would need an article if it were used in the singular "...find a thing...". In the plural, no article is used "...find things...", and given the context, it seems that a plural was probably intended. The context is the adverb "sometimes" which suggests multiple occasions, and the fact that 8 examples follow.

The phrase itself seems to come from [this twitter post](https://twitter.com/DiscoverMag/status/830396051148435456). When the same link was [first posted on facebook](https://www.facebook.com/DiscoverMag/posts/10154365608892076) the language was correct.